# Why copy multiple file use AppleScript cannot paste to 3rd party application?

Tags: swift, applescript, nspasteboard

I cannot paste to application, but in finder it works fine.

I also try use swift + NSPasteboard, seems to be the same problem.

What do I need to do to make it work totally same like finder?

Whether to use AppleScript or swift, I will take that.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

use framework "Appkit"
use scripting additions
use Finder : application "Finder"

property this : a reference to current application
property NSFileManager : a reference to NSFileManager of this
property NSImage : a reference to NSImage of this
property NSMutableArray : a reference to NSMutableArray of this
property NSPasteboard : a reference to NSPasteboard of this
property NSString : a reference to NSString of this
property NSURL : a reference to NSURL of this

property pb : missing value

on run input
    if input's class = script then set input to ¬
        Finder's selection as alias list

    init()
    clearClipboard()
    addToClipboard(input)
end run


to init()
    set pb to NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
end init

to clearClipboard()
    if pb = missing value then init()
    pb's clearContents()
end clearClipboard

to addToClipboard(fs)
    local fs

    set fURLs to NSMutableArray's array()
    set FileManager to NSFileManager's defaultManager()

    repeat with f in fs
        set f to do shell script "realpath '" & f & "'"
        if f's class = alias then set f to f's POSIX path
        set fp to (NSString's stringWithString:f)'s ¬
            stringByStandardizingPath()
        if (FileManager's fileExistsAtPath:fp) then ¬
            (fURLs's addObject:(NSURL's fileURLWithPath:fp))
    end repeat

    if pb = missing value then init()
    pb's writeObjects:fURLs
    #pb's setPropertyList:(fURLs, NSPasteboard's PasteboardType)
end addToClipboard
```

Comment: What do you mean by "like Finder"?  Note that when called by the shell, `input` will be a _list_ of arguments.

Comment: @red_menace copy action like finder, cmd + c, I want my script work same like that.

Comment: Command-C from the Finder copies several values to the clipboard, including file URLs and images.  Your example uses several path methods - are you wanting to copy multiple values for each of the selected items?

Comment: @red_menace yes, my example only working in finder application, but I other app, I cannot paste them. you can try it, if you paste to office document or some chat window, nothing happened.

Comment: Your example works if you change the initial comparison of the input’s class (when called by the shell, `input` will be a _list_ not a _script_), and then only for a single item.  I’m still trying to figure out _exactly_ what you are wanting copied to the clipboard, since you are working with aliases, posix paths, the results of some other shell script, and file URLs.

Comment: just normal file, such as txt、zip file, sorry I don't konw posix paths and file URLS is the same meaning

Comment: So copy from Finder to the other app works, copy from your app to the Finder works and copy from your app to the other app doesn't work? Did you compare the pasteboard contents?

Comment: yes, I used paste, file exists, but unusable